# Docker OnlyOffice - Nginx 111 Error

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm using the OnlyOffice DocumentServer (docker version) with my web-accplication. The online-editor runs fine, but when trying to edit a document the online-editor says "Download failed".

After that action the following error appears in my nginx error log:

```
2016/01/12 12:18:41 [error] 509#0: *230 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.3, server: , request: "GET /coauthoring/doc/LCFRY42GU6qpRha5jQ4G/c/info HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/doc/LCFRY42GU6qpRha5jQ4G/c/info", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/OfficeWeb/apps/documenteditor/main/index.html?_dc=0&lang=en"
```

nginx.config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

docker containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
a78b6511ed58        onlyoffice/communityserver   "/bin/sh -c 'bash -C "   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 5222/tcp   trusting_leavitt
db2bf7758cf5        onlyoffice/documentserver    "/bin/sh -c 'bash -C "   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          80/tcp, 443/tcp                                      onlyoffice-document-server
```

Comment: Pleas i want to ask can i run the editors in my browser locally?

Comment: Yes you can. Which version are you using?

Comment: The Version doesn't matter, But i prefer the latest version.

Comment: The version does matter! If you're using the enterprise version from ONLYOFFICE use the enterprise-install.sh script (wget http://download.onlyoffice.com/install/enterprise-install.sh) and follow this guide: http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/docker/enterprise/enterprise-script-installation.aspx. Differently if you're not using the enterprise version, then you have to run the docker container manually!

Comment: Could you guide me how to run the docker container manually?